# speaker dependent speech recognition engin with sdk

Tags: speech-recognition

I want to do a little apllication, does any one know of a good  speaker dependent speech recognition engin with sdk. (not speech to text engins)

thank you,

Efrat

Comment: What is the difference between "speech recognition" and "speech to text"? They sound like the same thing to me.

Answer (score 1):

[Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/) is probably along the lines of what you're looking for. It's an open-source speech recognition platform, and an ongoing project at Carnegie-Mellon University.

Comment: Sphinx is a superset of what the OP is looking for.

Sphinx is very nice, but it aims for the most complex problem: a large-vocabulary continuous speaker-independent speech recognition. Consequently, it demands considerable computing power to perform recognition - not the best choice for small, (computing) power constrained situations.

Answer (score 1):

I used sphinx-4 to arrive at an acccuracy of 82.25%. I am figuring out how to increase it greater than 95%. I am transcribing only one persons voice so if a speaker dependent system will be helpful that will be great. vocabulary is around 40,000 words. I have a dual core system and i could easily run sphinx-train and sphinx4 decoder though the trainer takes a day to train 40 hours of audio that i have and the decoder is realtime.

I want to know if there is a product / open-source library that i can make use of to increase my accuracy percentage.

Thanks,
Dharani

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate. What platform? What size vocabulary? What performance constraints? Continuous? Semi-continuous? What do you mean by "not speech to text engine"?

If you need something simple and small, you might want to try [EARS](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/comp.speech/Section6/Recognition/ears.html) written in C and not very big, probably good for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

there are speaker dependent engins, they are more primitive, like allot of the cellphones have. the do not attempt to convert to text, they just do signal comparison. and that what I need.

Comment: If you are going to clarify your question, you should edit your question directly. Instead you added an answer, which many people might not see.